# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource count cannot be found in the main bundle'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

So I have a swift/spritekit game that I've released.

Unfortunately, I'm getting reports of crashes on iPhone 5C's running iOS 8.1.

So I downloaded iOS 8.1 simulators and tested it and sure enough it crashes after the splash screen :(

It throws this error:

```
 NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource count cannot be found in the main bundle'

 *** First throw call stack:

 //stuff

 )
 libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've tried googling but it's not returning anything particular.
Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: check is file available in your Resource,because according to error not able to found file,

Comment: Oh `count` is an audio file. I misread it as part of the error thrown, not a resource name. Turns out that I forgot to put the file format in when loading: `count.wav`. Having added `.wav`, it no longer crashes. I guess in more recent iOS's, it doesn't need a file format implicitly declared. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: Welcome Bro,Yes that is ture ,this should be resource issue,.if comment useful for you mark as accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource `count` seen in the error thrown, is a resource file:

`NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Resource` **count** `cannot be found in the main bundle'`

In `iOS 8`, audio resources loaded into `SKActions` using `playSoundFileNamed`, require file formats to be included in the file name:

`let count = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("count.wav", waitForCompletion: false)`

After adding `.wav`, everything works as expected.

Thank you JP_Mob for pointing this out in the comment section of the question.